# Intuition behind transverse planes and regular curves

Tags: differential-geometry

I am working on a practice question for differential geometry and reviewing the provided solutions - but I am having a bit of trouble connecting the ideas of transverse planes and regular curves,

The question is this:

> Prove that if all normal lines of a connected surface $\sum$ meet a
>   fixed straight line, then every point of $\sum$ has a neighbourhood
>   that is contained in a surface of revolution.

The solution proceeds as follows:

Let $r$ be a fixed line which is met by the normals of the surface $\sum$. Consider the plane $Q$ which is perpendicular to the line $r$ and contains a point $p \in \sum$.

Here is where my confusion is, the solution then says:

**Since the normal at $p$ meets the line $r$, it must be that $Q$ is transverse to the tangent plane at $p$. Thus, in a neighbourhood of $p$, $Q \cap \sum$ is regular curve.**

Looking up the definition of transverse, it says that *smooth manifolds intersect transversally if at every point of intersection, their separate tangent spaces at that point together generate the tangent space of the ambient manifold at that point.*

I'm having a bit of trouble with this definition - if $Q$ and $T_p \sum$ are transverse, does this mean that the tangent vectors of $p$ in $Q$ and $T_p \sum$  generate the tangent space at $p$? (Would this be the whole space?) - what is the 'ambient manifold' in this case? Is it the curve where $Q$ and $T_p \sum$ intersect?

Why does this then mean that $Q \cap \sum$ is a regular curve?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the ambient space is $\mathbb{R}^3$. Hence $T_p\mathbb{R}^3$ is just $\mathbb{R}^3$ with center shifted to $p$ (it is not formal description, just how to feel it).

If we are given with two surfaces $\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2$ containing $p$ then we call them trasverse at $p$ if $T_p\Sigma_1 \cup T_p\Sigma_2$ generates $T_p\mathbb{R}^3.$ Intuitively, two surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are transvere at $p,$ if their tangent spaces at $p$ are different.

In your case $\Sigma_2$ is just a plane $Q,$ so it's tangent space at $p$ is just $Q$ in $T_p\mathbb{R}^3.$ Hence now transversality at $p$ means that
$Q\cup T_p\Sigma$ generates $T_p\mathbb{R}^3.$ It holds since $Q$ contains normal vector to $\Sigma$ (Crutial thing is that $n\not\in T_p\Sigma$).

Everything is smooth here, hence transversality at $p$ implies that we have similar situation in neighberhoud $V$ around that point (simply we cannot have the situation where at $p$ plane $Q$ contain normal vector and eveywhere around it is tangent to $\Sigma$).

Now we jump to the regularity issue. As we deal with the surface, in order to define one, we require charts and hence regular maps from open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3.$ Let $$\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\supset U\rightarrow\Sigma\subset R^3$$
be a homeomorphism such that $\phi(x)=p.$ We say that $\phi$ is regular at $x$ if $d_x\phi:T_x\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow T_p\mathbb{R}^3$ has maximal rank (that is 2). Equivalently Jacoby matrix of $\phi$ at $x$ has rank 2.

In similar manner we would say that $\gamma=\Sigma\cap Q\cap V$ is a regular curve if there exists homeomorphism
$$\psi:(a,b)\rightarrow\gamma$$
such that $\psi$ is regular everywhere (its Jacoby matrix at every point has rank 1, equvalently $\psi'(x)\neq 0$ for every $x\in(a,b)$).

The question is how can we find such chart $\psi.$ It can be constructed from $\phi,$ but details require implicit function theorem.